# Is it dangerous if I do not connect the ATX shield to ground?

Tags: power-supply, safety

I'm living in an Asian country and there isn't a ground connection provided on sockets here. There is only L (live) and N (neutral) so I need to use a 3-to-2 converter. It means that the ATX case does not connect to ground like in other countries and when I touch the case I feel hurt by electricity.

When using a volt meter to measure, it tells me that the computer case reaches ~80v AC between me and the computer (Ground ---> Me ---> Computer).

I found an ATX power supply circuit and I found that the ATX shield is connected to the ATX AC input circuit between the L and N lines and there are two capacitors in the middle.

I'm very new to electronics and I don't know why they connect the shield like that and I think it may be dangerous in my case? As I see the shield is connected directly to the L line so it's very dangerous if I don't connect the case to ground?

See the circuit here : [image]

Comment: Which mains outlet does your country use?

Comment: Better to use a laptop having a double-insulated power adapters and not risk your life! The 19 volts will be much safer, if not more energy efficient.

Answer (score 3):

**EMI shielding**

Look at C2/C3. This is a capacitive voltage divider that indeed will make your computer's case carry a voltage of approximately half the line voltage when not connected to ground. When your computer is not grounded and you touch the case you may feel the tingling and it *should* not reach a dangerous level. The two capacitors are there to improve the casing's performance for high frequency shielding (which a power supply like this as a lot of), so you mustn't remove them.

**Safety ground**

The other reason for the casing to be connected to ground is the fact that the entire case is made of metal and is easy to touch. Whenever some components fail *or* a wire comes loose, the entire case *may* carry line voltage and that can be leathal. When connected to ground, either the internal fuse will blow or an GCFI  (Ground Fault Circuit Interruptor) in your home will trip.

Comment: Can i replace the "Ground" with an other 0v source instead ? What is the output voltage of neutral line ?

Comment: Can I replace "Ground" => No.

Comment: What is the output voltage of neutral line => Theoretically 0V, in practice this line will carry several volts. You can not use neutral as safety ground, it is dangerous.

Comment: Can you explain why i cannot replace "ground" with other source. As i understand, is that true when i say earthing is for electricity run from high voltage point (the ATX case) to ground and therefore no electricity can be found in the ATX case more ?

Comment: @Wuthian Could you please clarify what you mean? It is not clear from your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here are the capacitors, as other have mentioned.

Main problem with capacitors, except form the already mentioned voltage divider, are their failure modes. If the power supply is actually safe and contains properly rated components, then you should be safe from capacitor failure.

The capacitors C2 and C3 should be Y class capacitors which should be self-healing (meaning that a continuous short through the capacitor cannot happen) and be flame-retardant (which means that they should not catch on fire and continue burning). There is a limited leakage current which can go through those capacitors from the live and neutral into the ground. If my calculations are correct, the highest RMS current you can get through those capacitors is around 0.5 mA.

Next, we have C4 capacitor which is connected between neutral and live. IT should be X class capacitor which should be capable of surviving high voltage spikes that can be found on power lines and be flame-retardant. Its failure should not be capable of causing an electric shock, but it can cause a short-circuit.

Both of those capacitor types should be tested by safety agencies and be appropriately marked.

Now a little bit about how it's done in the "real world":
From my experience, cheaper computer power supplies often do not have filtering capacitors installed and often do not use appropriate capacitors. For example instead of a real Y class capacitor, a 2000 V rated disk ceramic capacitor may be found. They are much more dangerous and could fail shorted causing equipment chassis to be at line potential in the worst case. In general, I wouldn't trust any computer power supply to be safe if it's not grounded and I wouldn't rely on the manufacturer to use safe components.

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous. If the line shorts to the case, the fuse will not blow, and the computer will be at line voltage, posing a hazard to anyone that touches it (or cables, headphones, etc, attached to it).

The capacitors are to shunt RF hash from the SMPS to earth.. reducing noise. The common mode choke and caps across the line attenuate noise reflected into the mains. Very common circuit on power input to SMPS.

The only way to be safe without ground is to have the circuit double insulated, is not the case here. (This is how plastic power supplies with no ground work, like for a laptop).

Comment: I see people in here never care or have trouble with it. No one death and it seem that it just hurt them without dangerous.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Can you please explain to me why would orientation of neutral and live be important in power supply which is being discussed here?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, but I mentioned this power supply on purpose. Here we know that the case is connected to disconnected ground wire and not to live or neutral (unless an internal short develops between case and live/neutral). Also case to line/neutral connection assumes that they are using polarized plugs, of which we can't be 100% certain.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a wire from the case of your computer to a cold water pipe or an 8 foot rod (made of copper or conductive metal) driven into the ground.

If you are feeling a tingle when you touch the case, that is a Bad Thing, and very unsafe.