# is it safe to have hot wire connected to ground (metal case, shield) via a capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ground, safety, shielding

I have opened a psu, and I saw a small capacitor is connected between one of the ac inputs and to the ground/shield. We don't have ground in our ac outlet, so a hot 110v ac line could be connected to the metal case via a capacitor, and I don't know if it is safe for me to touch the metal case. Should I removed that capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76249/is-it-dangerous-if-i-do-not-connect-the-atx-shield-to-ground?rq=1) may be related.

> EMI shielding
>
> Look at C2/C3. This is a capacitive voltage divider that indeed will make your computer's case carry a voltage of approximately half the line voltage when not connected to ground. When your computer is not grounded and you touch the case you may feel the tingling and it should not reach a dangerous level. The two capacitors are there to improve the casing's performance for high frequency shielding (which a power supply like this as a lot of), so you mustn't remove them.
>
> Safety ground
>
> The other reason for the casing to be connected to ground is the fact that the entire case is made of metal and is easy to touch. Whenever some components fail or a wire comes loose, the entire case may carry line voltage and that can be leathal. When connected to ground, either the internal fuse will blow or an GCFI (Ground Fault Circuit Interruptor) in your home will trip.

As suggested in the link try using a multimeter to get the voltage of your case.

> Connect a wire from the case of your computer to a cold water pipe or an 8 foot rod (made of copper or conductive metal) driven into the ground.
>
> If you are feeling a tingle when you touch the case, that is a Bad Thing, and very unsafe.

Comment: I read that already. it's different.

Comment: I think the suggestion to create your own ground is still a good bet from a safety standpoint.

Comment: As suggested in the link is there at any point another capacitor connected to the ground? It could be soldered to one of the screws indirectly and be being used as a capacitive voltage divider.

Comment: In my case, the capacitor is simply connected from one ac line to the ground. I don't think it's doing anything. If I remove it, will it make it safe?

Comment: Probably but it could also remove the filtering capability of the circuit to some extent. This could manifest as an increase in emitted EMI and an associated drop in wireless device performance. It could also be a decoupling capacitor?

Comment: Ultimately, the problem is that you do not have a grounded outlet, and the psu is counting on a ground connection. Depending on local regulations, you must either provide a grounded outlet, or use a GFI device to protect people. You are correct that if the capacitor fails bad things will happen.